# Share parts of mesh data across meshes

Tags: mesh, modifiers, linked-data

Greetings to the Blender community,

I'm using an Array Modifier on object A, with object B and C as caps. My problem is, that if I edit object A, the edge doesn't align with the caps anymore. Is there a way to share the shape of a specific part of the mesh, in my case the edge loop, between object A, B and C?

[image: example of my setup with an array Modifier (A) and two caps (B, C)]

If it's not possible then at least I know I can stop searching. :)

Best greetings,
Daisy

Comment: You can edit the vertices of different objects at the same time, you'll have to align them perfectly beforehand though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To take a somewhat @Gorgious-flavoured approach ;)..

You could use the *same mesh* for the head and tail caps, and the arrayed mid-section, but with different areas removed using a *Mask* modifier.

Assigning groups in face mode ensures the shared vertices are selected in each group:

[image]

Then 'Head', 'Mid', and 'Tail' objects can be <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> instanced, and each given a *Mask*  modifier, aimed at their respective groups. 'Mid' is the arrayed element...

[image]

The offset of the caps is unlikely to marry the midsection. As shown above, that can be fixed by giving them  a *Displace* modifier, along the array-axis.

Then you can edit the original, unmasked, instance, ('All', below,) and the array elements and caps will follow.

[image]

Comment: That is clever!

Comment: I literally thought: "What would @Gorgious do?" :D

Comment: Thank you a lot for this detailed answer! :)